# Textmate git commands fail with 'sh: line 1: git: command not found'

Tags: git, textmate

When trying to use some of the commands from the Git bundle for TextMate (eg. 'Show Uncommited Changes') I get an error message like 'sh: line 1: git: command not found'.

How do I make TextMate work with Git?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

http://theappleblog.com/2008/01/09/textmate-no-longer-a-reason-to-avoid-git/

> Set the TM_GIT shell variable in the
>   textmate preferences to your git
>   executable to work to solve the
>   command not found problem.

To find the path to your git binary, type "which git" on the command line. And of course, make sure Git is installed.

Comment: PS: for some reason, my colleague did not run into this problem on Snow Leopard, worked out of the box.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Snow Leopard. 

When I try to run "sh git" on the command line, I get this error:
/usr/local/git/bin/git: /usr/local/git/bin/git: cannot execute binary file

Comment: It looks like the explanation for this is that in TM `Settings -> Advanced -> Shell Variables` there is a (pointless?) default PATH of "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin", so even if you have asked GitInstaller to add git to the path, TextMate would skip it :-/

Comment: @conny You are right! Under Settings -> Advanced -> Shell Variables I had to add the TM_GIT variable with the path /usr/local/git/bin/git AND uncheck the  PATH "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" variable in order to get the bundle to work. I'm on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

If you already allowed [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list) to make git available to non-CLI applications (i.e. it planted a file in */etc/paths.d/git*) then you could just..:

```
Untick the PATH shell variable set by default in the textmate preferences.
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently run in the same problem with Snow Leopard, and none of the above solutions was apperaring to be working. So I made a symlink in `/usr/bin` to my git executable file like this:

```
cd /usr/bin

sudo ln -s `which git` git
```

then relaunched `Textmate` and it worked like a charm, without adding any variable or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Also, once you add the TM_GIT var, restart TextMate. Didn't work for me after the preference change without a restart.

Answer (score 0):

@Radamanthus You shouldn't run "sh git" from your commandline. You should run "git" directly. Also, you should use the which command (run "which git") to get a path to your git binary (as mentioned by @John Millikin).

Answer (score 0):

Add the location of your git to the PATH shell variable in `TextMate > Preferences... > Advanced > Shell Variables`.